# Drawer Items are not shown where drawer opens successfully

Tags: android

This is my activity `onCreate` function where I want to add data to Listview in  Drawer
data is added successfully but no data is shown in drawer when I try to add drawer, 
No error is shown is the Logcat.

```
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView drawer_list;
    String[] menu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //mySchedule=new Schedule();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Contact Us"};
        dLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer_list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drawer);
        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
        if(adapter!=null){
        drawer_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else{
            System.out.print("adapter emepty");
        }

        drawer_list.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        drawer_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                  });

    }
```

This is the Layout Drawer Layout file.........

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg015"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvEvents"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:background="#555555"
             android:text="Today&apos;s Events"
             android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
             android:textSize="18sp" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/scheduleView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvEvents"
         android:layout_height="209dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvClasses"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scheduleView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:text="Today&apos;s Classes"
        android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/classesView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvClasses"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="210dp" />



         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/tvTasks"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/classesView"
             android:text="Today&apos;s Task"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
             android:background="#555555"
             android:textSize="18sp" />

          <ListView
              android:id="@+id/taskView"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tvTasks"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="210dp"
          />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#fff"/>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The drawer opens without any data!

Comment: Hello, please update your question with proper syntax!

Comment: have u tried setting the background black? May be its there but text is white in color